# How to only quit current QQmlApplicationEngine while using Qt.quit() instead of the whole QGuiApplication?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml

I make these codes to have a better understanding for my question:

main.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication([])

engine1 = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine1.load("hello.qml")

engine2 = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine2.load("hello.qml")

app.exec_()
```

hello.qml

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Button"
        onPressed: Qt.quit()
    }

}
```

After pressing the button, both windows are closed. This is not what I expected.

Comment: Please explain why do you need 2 engines?

Comment: Just an example. In fact, sometimes I want to create two qml windows in a .py file, but when one window exits with Qt.quit(), both windows exit together. I would like to know how to create qml windows in the same .py file without the two windows affecting each other.

Comment: I guess that QML engine is a kind of singleton. This is certainly not the case and you can create several instances but looking at the docs, for example [qmlRegisterType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) doesn't get some engine pointer so for what engine the new type will be registered? Actually several engines it is nonsense and you will never need it. All you want can be realized in pure QML.

Comment: If you have time please take a look at my new example. I have not high enough level to reply to people, sorry. @folibis

Comment: @lxchx I have removed your edit because instead of helping to understand your initial problem, add another one unnecessarily, so I recommend you create a new post where you ask about your new problem (your new example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

That's the default behavior pointed out in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details):

> List of configuration changes from a default QQmlEngine:
>
> - **Connecting Qt.quit() to QCoreApplication::quit()**
> - Automatically loads
>   translation files from an i18n directory adjacent to the main QML
>   file.
>
>   - Translation files must have "qml_" prefix e.g. qml_ja_JP.qm.
> - Translations are reloaded when the QJSEngine::uiLanguage /
>   Qt.uiLanguage property is changed.
> - Automatically sets an incubation
>   controller if the scene contains a QQuickWindow.
> - Automatically sets a
>   QQmlFileSelector as the url interceptor, applying file selectors to
>   all QML files and assets.
>
> The engine behavior can be further tweaked
> by using the inherited methods from QQmlEngine.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So there are 2 alternatives:

- remove the connection:

  ```py
  for engine in (engine1, engine2):
      engine.disconnect()
  ```
- Use QQmlEngine instead of QQmlApplicationEngine.

---

### Proper Solution

Going to the background problem that is how to close the window when the user presses a button so you should not use [`Qt.quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method) but instead invoke the [`close()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#close-method) method of the window:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Button"
        onPressed: root.close()
    }
}
```

You should only use [`Qt.quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method) if you want to exit the entire application.

Comment: Regarding the first method, the window does not close after calling Qt.quit(), and I get the warning "Signal QQmlEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it. " . But what I want is to close the corresponding window instead of doing nothing.

Comment: Regarding the second method, QQmlEngine seems cumbersome using existing .qml files, I haven't tried it yet, but I'll give it a try. I think it's strange to use this method for this purpose though.

Comment: If you have time please take a look at my new example.

Comment: Note: Your new example introduces a new problem (hint: check out the scope concept in python) so it doesn't help in understanding your initial problem so remove that edit. Check what you added as it is the right solution and create a new post asking why your new example fails.

Comment: Ok, I just started using Stack Overflow and am not sure about some of the rules here.

Comment: @lxchx then read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]